# organising classes / folder structure for TDD-based development

Tags: file-structure, naming, tdd

Due to test-driven development, one ends up with many classes doing just one thing.  It is quite a headache just to see **where** such classes would be placed inside the folder structure.

First of all, is it considered a bad-pattern, to put related classes in the same file?

Any suggestion on what one uses in actual-production environments?

Comment: Hi Karl, unfortunately your question is offtopic here according to [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: And by the way, "doing just one thing" is a good approach unless you start trying to split a single business function into several classes. Think of `List` class - it has a single function but does multiple things (adds, deletes items etc). I don't see issues in putting small related classes into one file as long as resulting file is of manageable size

Comment: Are you asking about Test Classes or functional classes? These are two different concerns.

Comment: What would be the naming pattern for files with multiple classes inside?

Comment: Also it is not because of TDD. It's because of following SOLID principles (too) well.

Comment: @MikeBrown I am referring to Functional classes, not the actual test-classes.  For test classes, I organize them exactly where the class being tested is, but in a separate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should put one class in one file.  That way it is easy to find the pertinent code when making changes.  I think that it would be more of a headache to have to try to remember how the classes were organized when looking for the code that I am trying follow.  You aren't creating these files for the computer but for the future developer (it might be you) that is going to be trying to find some bug or add a new feature.  And files make that easier to do because `A.class` is an easier to look for than `Stuff.class`.

If you create a directory structure that groups similar classes together, that can reduce some of your headache.

Answer (score 1):

In languages that support it, why not use [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29)? That should make it clear what the organization is, regardless of the folder structure.